# Raster operation with grass.mapcalc

Tags: python, grass-gis

I need to iteratively add each raster map of viewshed analysis obtained from  a series of single observer locations. For this i used grass.mapcalc with Python (GRASS 7 for Windows). However, my problem is that in `grass.mapcalc` you cannot allow functions like the following that we do apply in normal programming.

```
grass.mapcalc("viewshedN = viewshed + ViewshedN", overwrite = True, quiet = True)
```

Therefore, i have a trouble in adding each raster iteratively. Is it possible to add an incremental number to the output each time a new raster created? I just tried this in a loop with an integer variable but failed (parse error) in the following code. Is there any other work around/ method or alternative to add each raster result iteratively in GRASS  with Python?

```
formula = 'viewshed' + str(i)          
grass.mapcalc(formula, overwrite = True, quiet = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the correct syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# r.mapcalc example in Python

import sys
import os
import atexit

import grass.script as grass

def cleanup():
    pass

def main():

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options, flags = grass.parser()

    inmap = "slope"
    outmap = "slope_div10"
    # some junk example calculation
    grass.mapcalc("$outmap = float($inmap / $value)", inmap = inmap, outmap = outmap, value = 10.0)

    atexit.register(cleanup)
    sys.exit(main())
```

And the result:

```
GRASS 7.0.svn (nc_spm_08):~ > g.region rast=slope
GRASS 7.0.svn (nc_spm_08):~ > python mapcalc.py 
 100%

GRASS 7.0.svn (nc_spm_08):~ > r.info -r slope
min=0
max=38.68939

GRASS 7.0.svn (nc_spm_08):~ > r.info -r slope_div10
min=0
max=3.868939
```

See also the Wiki page:
http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library#r.mapcalc_example